# Is it possible to run java 10 with framework spring 5?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, jetty

I want java 10 work with spring 5, but I can't find any info if it's possible or not to make both work together.
Does someone know how to run java 10 with Servlet Containers ?

Thanks,

Comment: Normally this setup should just work. Have you tried it? Failed it? If yes, how did it fail?

Comment: I set up java 10 with spring-boot but i can run the application and I read tomcat7 can run java 10.

Comment: There is only a java 10 annotation/bytecode scanning step that currently fails - https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/2397  (but you can upgrade your ASM jar manually and it'll be fine)

Comment: Thank @JoakimErdfelt I will try it this weekend and let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least for now on [github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/What%27s-New-in-Spring-Framework-5.x) page they claims:

> Full compatibility with JDK 9 for development and deployment.
>     On classpath as well as module path (with stable automatic module names).
>     Framework build and test suite passes on JDK 9 (runs on JDK 8 by default).

Seems that it is not yet tested/integrated with java 10.